# Let $M$ is a squared matrix. Find $M^n,n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, induction

Let $M=XAX^{-1}$ where $  X=      \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        2 & 3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$, $A=        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        2 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Find $M^{n},n\in\mathbb{N}$

Attempt:

Inductive method:

$M^{1}=        \begin{bmatrix}
        -11 & 8\\
        -18 & 13  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

$M^{2}=        \begin{bmatrix}
        -23 & -64\\
        144 & -135  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

$M^{3}=        \begin{bmatrix}
        1405 & -376\\
        846 & 747  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

In order to find $M^{n}$, this method requires finding the closed form of sequences for all entries of a matrix $M$ (first sequence would be $-11,-23,1405,...$).

What is the simpler method to find $M^{n}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that
$$
M^2=(XAX^{-1})(XAX^{-1})=XAX^{-1}XAX^{-1}=XA^2X^{-1}.
$$
You can similarly show that $M^n=XA^nX^{-1}$.

So, you only need to take powers of $A$.  And, perhaps, that will be a bit easier to spot patterns for.

Comment: [Indeed](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B1%2C0%5D%2C%5B2%2C1%5D%5D%5E5)...